# Insert 2 values into a linked list node

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working with a linked list with a struct that looks like this:

```
struct theStruct{
    int variable1;
    char* variable2;
    struct theStruct* next;
};
```

As you can see I want to insert two variables into each of my nodes. The problem I have is that I am currently reading from a textfile and variable 1 is obtained in the beginning of the row and variable 2 in the end so I am not able to put them in at the same time (at least not that I am aware of). This is how I have written but without success.

```
...
reading file
....
 while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(counter == 1)
        {
            newToken = token;
        }

        if(counter == 3)
        {
            temp = (theStruct*)malloc(sizeof(theStruct));
            temp->variable1= atoi(token);
            temp->variable2 = newToken;
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
...
```

Afterwards when I try to print I only get the value from temp->variable1 and temp->variable2 contains some weird characters.
I want to somehow hold the first variable until I get my other variable without allocating new memory for temp but I have no clue how to do this. I hope I gave enough information for you guys to give me some kind of lead or clue to how to fix my problem.

Comment: Could you post some more of the code? I guess token is the file content, but I don't get what you're using count for. You said variable2 is at the end of the row but you're assigning token to it when count is 1

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the file has a certain pattern for every row in which I need the variable on place 1 and 3. token is the name where I save the value I get from strtok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
temp->variable2 = newToken;
```

you are pointing `temp->variable2` somewhere in the middle of whatever you first passed to `strtok()` -- that is likely something that is going to be overwritten.  You probably want to make a copy of it:

```
temp->variable2 = strdup(newToken);
```

This is one reason some people feel strtok() is fraught with peril.

Comment: Thank you! It finally started to work, sorry for the bad describing in the beginning. I guess I will never do this mistake again :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are doing this for multiple lines in the file.
Consider a program along these lines::

```
if open file fails die a horrible death
init linked list
while fgets from file a whole line != NULL {
    temp = malloc(sizeof(things));
    token = strtok(line, "!");
    while (token != NULL) {
        decide where to insert token in temp->XXXX
        token = strtok(NULL, "!");
    }
    insert temp into your linked list (probably)
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I am doing, it's just that I aquire variable1 and variable2 at different times in the code which doesn't allow me to allocate memory for temp since it will be reallocated by the time I get the other variable

Comment: variable1 and variable2 are on the same line, right?

Comment: Yes they are, but as I am using a while loop: while(token != NULL)

Comment: Where does `token` come from?

Comment: the token is the variable I use to save down the different "words" in the file to, example of pattern: food!sport!movies etc and then I save food in token and use strtok to keep them from eachother

Comment: Okay thanks, but I kinda already had that. U gave me an idea tho but there is something wrong here which I can't seem to grasp. I updated the code at the top, could you take a look?

Comment: The problem I get with this code is that when I print the list out, variable1 prints all of its different values meanwhile as variable2 only prints out the last added value.

Comment: I added a new answer, please see that.